# MySql write is extremely slower after separating database from web server

Tags: mysql

I have both Apache/PHP and MySql running on the same server but during peak time (about 2-3 hours a day) the server is very slow. So, following the most common recommendation, I setup MySql in a separate machine (on the same local network with 1 Gbit interconnect). Now, during off-peak, both reads and writes are slightly slower (seems logical since I use TCP/IP instead of sockets), however, during peak time, the reads are much faster but the writes are extremely slow. Any recommendations on what might be the cause? Any suggestions for optimization? Please let me know if you need any tests/logs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I Would Suggest You to Use RestAPI in order to service your application with resources. I have tried using MySql/Apache combo but i faced a lot of difficulties with the many requests.